# Implementar loop com programação funcional Java

Tags: java, java-8, programação-funcional

```
private List<String> getPermissoes(TipoUsuario tipoUsuario) {

    List<String> permissoes = new ArrayList();
    for (Permissao permissao : tipoUsuario.getPermissoes()) {
        permissoes.add(permissao.getNome());
    }        
    return permissoes;
}
```

Eu gostaria de implementar isso, mas usando programação funcional. Tentei o seguinte:

```
tipoUsuario.getPermissoes().stream().map(permissao -> Permissao::getNome()).collect();
```

Tá errado, eu sei, mas a ideia é essa.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A sintaxe `Permissao::getNome` é um [*method reference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), ou seja uma referência ao método `getNome` da classe `Permissao`. É diferente de uma chamada ao método, por isso não pode estar no corpo do *lambda*.

Para usar o *method reference*, basta você usá-lo sem os parênteses.

Além disso, o método [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) precisa receber algum coletor para ele saber qual deve ser o tipo retornado. Na classe [`java.util.stream.Collectors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) já tem vários collectors prontos. Por exemplo, se você quiser retornar os nomes em uma lista, basta usar [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--). Exemplo:

```
List<String> nomes = tipoUsuario.getPermissoes().stream()
    .map(Permissao::getNome).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Outra alternativa é chamar o método `getNome()` em vez de usar o *method reference*, e no caso ficaria assim:

```
List<String> nomes = tipoUsuario.getPermissoes().stream()
    .map(permissao -> permissao.getNome()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Perfeito. Isso é o que chamo de mais estilo. Vlw @hkotsubo. Muito Obrigado de vdd